# Tension and wire/bar and Young module

Tags: thermodynamics

I was doing some questions and reading a things in thermodynamics, when was asked to calc the Tension variation of a dependured wire when we varies the temperature, maintaining the length constant. In the end, i founded (and it was right) that $$\delta F = -YA \alpha \delta\theta$$
Where Y is the young module

A is the cross sec area

$\alpha$ the linear coefficient

$\theta$ the temperature

I don't know if the answer makes intuitively sense,I would expect the tension to increase when we increase the wire temperature, since it will make the wire to expand and to press more the wall (or whatever is holding it). Why is this a wrong way of think? What physically makes the tension increase if we cold the wire?

Comment: If the force is pushing inward on the bar, we call this compression, not tension.

Answer (score 3):

Tension causes elongation, and thermal expansion causes elongation. These phenomena are expressed by simple Hooke's Law augmented to incorporate thermal expansion:

$$\varepsilon =\frac{\sigma}{E}+\alpha\Delta T,$$

where $\varepsilon$ is strain, $\sigma$ is stress, $E$ is Young's modulus, $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient, and $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature. We can also express this in terms of elongation $\Delta L$ as

$$\Delta L =\frac{FL}{AE}+\alpha L\Delta T,$$

where $L$ is the original length, $F$ is the axial load, and $A$ is the cross-sectional area. If we stretch or compress a bar, clamp the ends in place, and change the temperature, we have $\Delta L=0$, from which we obtain the equation you derived (in slightly different notation).

> I would expect the tension to increase when we increase the wire temperature, since it will make the wire to expand and to press more the wall (or whatever is holding it). Why is this a wrong way of think?

Again, tension causes elongation, and thermal expansion causes elongation. But this doesn't mean that thermal expansion causes tension. In fact, it eases any tension required to maintain a certain elongation, because stress-driven elongation and thermal-expansion-driven elongation superpose.

> What physically makes the tension increase if we cold the wire?

If cooling a stress-free wire would tend to cause thermal contraction, then tension becomes necessary to maintain the same length. The contraction and elongation effects are again superposed.